# how to put repeater control ( or any other asp server control ) in autocomplete extender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, repeater

i tried this code

```
**java script to add html controls in autocomplete**

<script type = "text/javascript">
function Employees_Populated(sender, e) {
    var employees = sender.get_completionList().childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("DIV");
        div = "<table border='5px' width='400px'><tr><td><img style = 'height:50px;width:50px' src = 'photos/"
        + employees[i]._value + ".jpg' /></td><td><button name='BtnG' id='gbqfb'></asp:Button></td></tr></Table><br/> ";
        employees[i].appendChild(div);
    }
}
function OnEmployeeSelected(source, eventArgs) {
    var idx = source._selectIndex;
    var employees = source.get_completionList().childNodes;
    var value = employees[idx]._value;
    var text = employees[idx].firstChild.nodeValue;
    source.get_element().value = text;
}
</script>
```

**server side code to bind data base in autocomplete**

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select Id, Name, City from" +
         " webInfo where Name like @SearchText + '%'";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText);
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cn.Open();
        List<string> employees = new List<string>();
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                employees.Add(AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender
                   .CreateAutoCompleteItem(string.Format("{0} {1} {0}",sdr["Name"], sdr["City"],sdr["ID"]),
                   sdr["Id"].ToString()));
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
        return employees;

    }
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

i want to show grid view or repeater with the buttons inside them but how to do that i do not know

Answer (score 0):

there no need to use autocomplete here , you just bind all the data in repeater and sort thier according to text field character

you have to just find the input character in tr of repeater,
if found make visible other all tr hidden

Use Jquery

Comment: i have to load all database in the repeater. another option is just make an ajax call when there is text typed in text box and bind the repeater, but how to do that

Comment: it is simple first bind the data in repeater after on textchange call the jQuery function in that function you have find your some char in every tr of repeater if it found, make tr visible true else false

Comment: no for this i have to fetch and bind all the data from database, in the repeater first, than to apply search is a bed idea. it will hit performance. what i want is on text change make an ajax call run the search query against the database and bind the result in  repeater and show it just near the text box. bur it will be good if i just able to put repeater control in the autocomplete extender it wiil save my design efforts.

Comment: please elaborate more i can not understand i am new